# How to add elements from one array(Array 1) to another array(Array 2) after checking for a specific condition in array 1?

Tags: arrays, swift

In the below code I want to first check the array[b] for elements less than 100 and then add all those elements to another array called resultArray. As it stands, the elements less than 100 are getting printed to console but I want to add those elements to the resultArray. What is the best way to do this in Swift 3?

```
var value = 1
var resultArray: [Int]
var b = [23,34,67,2,89,76,874]
for var c in b {
    if c < 100 {

        print("Numbers less than 15 are \(c) ")
    }
    c += 1
}
```

Comment: Note that the statement `c += 1` at the end of the loop body is completely unnecessary and has no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a simple filter:

```
let b = [23,34,67,2,89,76,874]
let r = b.filter { $0 < 100 }
print(r)
```

This outputs:

> [23, 34, 67, 2, 89, 76]

If you wanted to use the code you started with, you need to append `c` to `resultArray` and make a few other minor tweaks:

```
var resultArray: [Int] = []
let b = [23,34,67,2,89,76,874]
for c in b {
    if c < 100 {
        resultArray.append(c)
    }
}
print(resultArray)
```

Another option (thanks Martin R) would be:

```
var resultArray: [Int] = []
let b = [23,34,67,2,89,76,874]
for c in b where c < 100 {
    resultArray.append(c)
}
print(resultArray)
```

Comment: Or: `for c in b where c < 100 { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

It is better to start an array name with a and the resulting array, according to your conditional, is given by

```
 var a = [23,34,67,2,89,76,874]
 var resultArray = [Int]()

    for var x in a {
    if x < 100 {
        resultArray.append(x)
    }
}
```

Here, x takes only one value at each iteration. If your conditional is matched then the value of x is added to your resulting array.

If you want to sort your resultArray and print to the console then try out the following lines after the loop:

```
resultArray.sort()
print(resultArray)
```

The output after sorting is:

```
[2, 23, 34, 67, 76, 89]
```